# Problemas con permisos, carpeta en servidor web linux

Tags: php, linux, apache

Bueno, tengo un servidor web apache en linux, si ingreso con mi usuario por via ftp puedo editar los archivos del site web sin problemas, la cosa es cuando dentro de mi aplicación genero un exportar, y tengo el siguiente error.

```
Warning: file_put_contents(temp/SAC140FAGI20190709NI.txt): failed to open 
stream: Permission denied in 
/www/Sitios/Dulas/html/circular_030/controlador_exportar_circular.php on 
line 32 Call
```

Obviamente por ftp el usuario que uso esta con sus permisos, pero como estoy haciendo una solicitud directamente desde el sitio web, no se que permisos configurar, puesto que  en estos archivos el propietario y grupo son appuser:appuser y appuser ademas de tener su propio grupo también esta dentro del grupo apache. Todos los archivos y carpetas están con permisos de lectura y escritura en el grupo y usuario propietario, pero solo lectura para el resto de usuarios.

Comment: el usuario o el grupo debe ser `www-data`

Comment: Gracias JackNavaRow, quien es el usuario grupo www-data, que finalidad cumple?

Comment: Y si no tengo este usuario en mi sistema?